# How can I visualize VCS status in dired?

Tags: dired, git

I'm particularly concerned with `git`, but I imagine this is a good place to use `vc`.  I want to emulate Atom's git integration with its file explorer:

[image: atom-git-integration]

How can I get something like this in `dired`?  I understand there are other tools for simulating a proper tree structure, but the normal `i/RET` workflow should work just fine.

Comment: Just to clarify (since I'm not familiar with Atom): Green would be untracked/new files.  Dark Grey is files in `.gitignore`, light grey is up-to-date and orange is modified?

Comment: @JonathanLeech-Pepin That's what is pictured, but faces are easy enough to `M-x customize` :)

Comment: @JonathanLeech-Pepin I don't use Atom myself so I don't know if even *it* does this, but it would really neat if dired knew when things had been deleted in the work tree.

Comment: I'm guessing this will need to end up being a `dired-vc` package that adjusts the faces of the files.  Google doesn't seem to come up with anything.  -> `dired-after-readin-hook` looks like an entry point for it (each listing is narrowed to after reading).

Comment: @JonathanLeech-Pepin After a bit of play, I think the trick will be parsing out the actual file names from that listing.  (Note that `(buffer-string)` is effectively the entire output of `ls`.)  Could potentially use `dired-get-filename`.

Comment: It's funny, the hook says it runs narrowed, but the `.el` file says run unnarrowed because you don't need to narrow.

Comment: @JonathanLeech-Pepin It will at any rate be narrowed to the current directory listing – might be useful when inserting directories. But then again, the ability to refresh the tree's status would be good – might *have* to be done all-together.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21383/discussion-between-jonathan-leech-pepin-and-sean-allred).

Comment: A simple way is to use `M-x vc-dir`.  It isn't quite the same as dired but it's pretty nice anyway.  If you really want VC on dired, I think the only option is to write elisp to do it.  Maybe not super hard since VC can already provide the information you need.

Comment: @TomTromey It doesn't seem that `vc-dir` will display unchanged files.  While I apropos for a controlling variable, do you know if there is one?

Comment: I looked but didn't immediately see one, sorry.

Comment: It looks like `vc-dir.el:1282` is responsible for highlighting entries, but it looks like the function doesn't even get called.

Comment: One could modify `vc-dir.el:1110` to do this, but @TomTromey is right: there is no actual toggle.

Comment: See also [this pull request](https://github.com/jaypei/emacs-neotree/pull/93) for Neotree.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can install [diff-hl](https://github.com/dgutov/diff-hl) from GNU ELPA and add the following to your init file:

```
(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook 'diff-hl-dired-mode)
```

But it doesn't color the lines. Instead, it shows statuses in the fringe (or the margin, if `diff-hl-margin-mode` is on). Looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Woah! Also, sorry! I checked back here [almost by accident](http://redd.it/2zt08q) :) I'll give this a go today and see if it can be modified to suit my needs. In the event that I can get something working, would you mind if I edited the necessary patches into your answer so it can be complete?

Comment: @SeanAllred Sure, as long as the added code uses the public functionality, and does not redefine any of the functions. In case you find you absolutely need that, better file a feature request.

Comment: Naturally :) Though I will note that 'public functionality' is difficult to determine in emacs lisp :)

Comment: @SeanAllred Well, vars and hook in this case, I guess. :)

Comment: I'm accepting this because it answers the question I asked as written, but future readers should note the [additional answer](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/10931/2264) I provided for neotree's new support of this.

Answer (score 2):

This is an 'incomplete' set of elisp that will provide the feature set.  Implementing a full list is left as an exercise (and/or as a full package to develop `dired-vc` (time-permitting)) for the reader.

Steps to complete the below with missing information:

1. Obtain a list of all symbols returned by `vc-state`
2. Define faces (`defface`) for each missing symbol
3. Adjust the `cond` block to include all those symbols

```lisp
(defun dired-fontify-vc ()
  (while (not (eobp))
    (let* ((inhibit-read-only t)
           (file (ignore-errors (file-name-nondirectory
                                 (dired-get-filename))))
           (state (ignore-errors (vc-state file))))
      (when (and file
                 state)
        ; (message "%s>%s" file state)
        (let ((beg (dired-move-to-filename))
              (end (dired-move-to-end-of-filename)))
          (cond
           ((eq state 'edited)
            (add-text-properties beg end '(font-lock-face edited-face)))
           ((eq state 'up-to-date)
            (add-text-properties beg end '(font-lock-face update-face)))))
        ))
    (dired-next-line 1)))

(add-hook 'dired-after-readin-hook 'dired-fontify-vc)

(defface edited-face
  '((t :foreground "orange"))
  "Foreground color for edited files")
(defface update-face
  '((t :foreground "white"))
  "Foreground color for up-to-date files.")
```

Comment: Two things: 1) This is a much slower solution, compared to what `diff-hl-dired` does (it uses the `dir-status-files` backend command), 2) this `update-face` is unreadable in the default theme.

Answer (score 2):

Not actually `dired`-based, but it is closer to the Atom screenshot provided.  As of [PR#93](https://github.com/jaypei/emacs-neotree/pull/93), `neotree` can display VCS status as part of the listing:

[image: screenshot]

Here is the configuration that would effect the screenshot above:

```
(setq neo-vc-integration '(char face))
```

The presence of `char` controls the `?` and `E` that you see.
The presence of `face` controls the highlighting.

Comment: That looks nice, but without any info about your configuration …

Comment: Belatedly addressed

Answer (score 0):

Not dired but [treemacs](https://github.com/Alexander-Miller/treemacs) does this.

Treemacs is a package that you install via package.el or similar.

e.g.

[image: Image of treemacs from Github project]

The colours show git status. For files White up to date, mauve changed, blue not in git. If a file is expanded e.g. README.org then these are the items provided by menu.