# Git track flag in Dired

Tags: magit, dired, git

How can I show an additional column in Dired, where I can see if the file is tracked or not by git in the current branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to look at [diff-hl](https://github.com/dgutov/diff-hl) and [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/9552/11934) on Stack Exchange. Basically, diff-hl puts the git status of files in a dir in the margin rather than in the column. Depending on what exactly you're looking for, this should suffice. Just add the `diff-hl` package, and use `(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook 'diff-hl-dired-mode)`

Comment: Superb! Thank you !